# Why does zero padding in Fourier domain lead to an inverse transform which is complex?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, interpolation, ifft

If I start off with a signal which has only real values, performing an fft and ifft returns the exact signal back with no complex entries as expected. But if I pad the fft with zeros to obtain interpolated values in the time domain, the inverse fft always turns out to be a complex double. I have taken care to perform the fftshift() and then pad on both sides, so that the symmetry is not broken. Following is an example code, that shows this behaviour. Am I looking at this the wrong way, or is the computational error after zero padding a bit too much? How do I overcome this?

Code:

```
%%%%%%%%%

x=linspace(0,2*pi,200);

y = sin(x)+sin(2*x);

Y = fftshift(fft(y));

n=400;

x1 = linspace(0,2*pi,n);

Y1 = zeros(1,n);

Y1((n-200)/2+1:end-(n-200)/2) = Y;

y2 = ifft(fftshift(2*Y1));

plot(x,y);

hold on;

plot(x1,y2(1:end),'x-');

isreal(y)==isreal(y2)

%%
```

Comment: Note: `Y2` is not defined, and why are you comparing at the end vs `Y2`, I guess it should be `y2`?

Comment: For comparison there is a FEX submission where you ca see how it is coded: [Frequency-domain-zero-padding](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/58854-frequency-domain-zero-padding-resampling--interpolation-)

Comment: my bad, it was a typo, it should be y2, but that is not the issue though

Comment: @Irreducible, I checked the code on that page. It does exact same thing. Only that, at the end before returning, only real part is considered. But, ignoring the imaginary part, just changes the signal. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Probably an off by one error, or not ignoring microscopic rounding-error values.  For the result of an IFFT to be strictly real (except for tiny numerical noise quantities), the complex input vector has to be exactly conjugate symmetric around element 0 (or around N/2 for even N).

Answer (score 0):

There are several, small issues with your code:

1. The number of samples of the original signal, and its FFT, should be odd. To see why, note that the first entry of the FFT is the zero-frequency component, which has no symmetric frequency. The number of *remaining* frequencies should be even, so that they can be split in two symmetric parts, and the additional zeros can be inserted between the two parts.
2. The time axes should not be created with `linspace`. Since `linspace` fixes *both* endpoints, you don't get an exact scale factor of `2`. To do that you need to create the axes manually with `:` (`colon`).
3. The second `fftshift` should be `ifftshift`. This is not important here, because the zero-padded FFT has even size and so `fftshift` and `ifftshift` coincide. But as a general rule you should use `ifftshift` to undo the action of `fftshift`.

So, the code becomes:

```
x = (0:200)/201*2*pi;
y = sin(x)+sin(2*x);
Y = fftshift(fft(y));
x1 = (0:401)/402*2*pi;
Y1 = [zeros(1,101) Y zeros(1,100)];
y2 = ifft(ifftshift(2*Y1)); % or fftshift, since length is even
plot(x,y,'o-');
hold on;
plot(x1,y2,'.:');
isreal(y)==isreal(y2)
max(abs(y-y2(1:2:end))) % should be of the order of eps
```

Now we can check that

- Both signals are real:

  ```
  >> isreal(y)==isreal(y2)
  ans =
    logical
     1
  ```

  A better test would be to check that the imaginary component of `y1` (which might not be exactly zero due to numerical precision issues) is of the order of `eps`.
- Every other sample of `y1` coincides with the corresponding sample in `y`, up to numerical errors of the order of `eps`:

  ```
  >> max(abs(y-y2(1:2:end)))
  ans =
       6.661338147750939e-16
  ```

[image]

Comment: Just a minor correction; the length of the inverse FFT does not have to be odd for conjugate symmetry to result in a real output.  The requirement is simply that Y(2:end) == conj(Y(end:-1:2)).  This implies that entry n/2 is real. 
 Take, for instance, `A = rand(3,1) + 1j*rand(3,1); Y = [10; A; 4; conj(flip(A))];  ifft(Y)`.  The length here is even, but the result is real.

Comment: @CKT What I meant is that the length has to be odd _if we want to be able to pad with zeros_. If it is even, the component at normalized frequency pi rad/s would have to be "split in two" to accomodate the zeros in between